# Spreadsheet Tag

Tags: discussion

Some people are using spreadsheets for statistical analysis. I have noticed that there is an [excel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel) tag. Or, some people use spreadsheets other than Excel. There are for instance questions related to LibreOffice.

I just wonder if it wouldn't be a good idea to introduce a more generic "Spreadsheet" tag? This tag could be used for Excel related questions next to the "Excel" tag, but also for questions related to other spreadsheets.

Comment: not many LibreOffice questions though http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=libreoffice

Comment: Also I would have never associated the `calc` tag with LibreOffice nor OpenOffice (although I suppose someone whom actually works with that software might). Perhaps it would be a good case for synonyms or a general renaming. calc is so generic I think I rather see libreoffice as the name (and it currently has only two questions with that tag).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say no, as your contemporary answer about Libre Office is not directly applicable to Excel. We could come close to extending the notion to almost all statistical software (e.g. although many answers ask for a solution in R, inevitably most of those same things could be accomplished in SAS, Stata, SPSS, etc.). I don't think a `stat-software` tag would be very helpful.

I think their could be situations in which a spreadsheet tag is useful (such as [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/10700/1036) question about using a spreadsheet for teaching purposes), but they are so few and far between its hard to see its usefulness (at this time). There are currently only 38 questions tagged with [Excel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel) at this time. It is not much of a burden to peruse either the excel tag or the [calc](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calc) tag to see if they have any information pertinent to spreadsheets in general.

Comment: In general, I've come to accept a more *laissez-faire* attitude about things such as tags as I've used the site more. If someone wants to implement a spreadsheet tag, go ahead and see if it gets adopted by the community in general. Just don't go and do a massive retagging on your own.

Comment: +1 I fully agree. It is like having r-or-splus tag...